# grab neighboring content in a query

Tags: query-posts, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'm grabbing a post based on a **querystring** parameter. How can I get the **neighboring** posts for a *previous* and *next* button?

This will get *tricky* when you're on the first/last items.

Here is how I'm getting the target post:

```
$the_id;
if($_GET['the_id']) $the_id = $_GET['the_id'];
$arr = array('post_type' => 'my_cpt', 'showposts' => 1);

if($the_id >= 0) {
    $arr['p'] = $the_id;
}

query_posts($arr);
```

*note that if there was now querystring param, I'm just loading from the *most recent* post of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [get_adjacent_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post). if nothing is returned for next/prev, get the first/last.

Edit- just noticed your custom post type, you'll also have to filter `get_previous_post_where` and `get_next_post_where` to pick up your cpt.

Comment: This is my first time using something like this. I've looked for examples and none of them are working so far. Will you kindly show me how this should look?